# Update view when pushing models to the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have quite a complex page in my application with lots of different models being shown. I live-update several of these models through a `/updates` REST call. I pass a `last_request_timestamp` parameter and it returns the models that were created or modified since the last call.

I add the models to the store by using `store.push(model, model_json)`. However, the templates are not updated after the models have been pushed. How can I ensure that there is a binding between the models in the store and the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The [Ember.js FAQ](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/) says

> Filters, on the other hand, perform a live search of all of the records in the store's cache. As soon as a new record is loaded into the store, the filter will check to see if the record matches, and if so, add it to the array of search results. If that array is displayed in a template, it will update automatically.
>
> ...
>
> Keep in mind that records will not show up in a filter if the store doesn't know about them. You can ensure that a record is in the store by using the store's `push()` method.

So in the controller for the view that I want to live-update, I use `filter()` on the store to fetch the models.

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  comments: function() {
    var postId = this.get('id');
    return this.get('store').filter('comment', function(comment) {
      return comment.get('post.id') == postId;
    });
  }.property('comments')
});
```

Now, whenever I `push()` a new `Comment` to store, it is automatically added to the appropriate post in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicitly push them into a collection that is being represented on the page by using `pushObject`.  `store.push` will return a live record, so you could do something like this.

```
var book_record = store.push('book', model_json);
this.get('controllers.books.content').pushObject(book_record);
```

That's assuming that the `BooksController` is a standard `ArrayController`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it requires two steps (but simple steps). You need to add it to the store and then save the record for it to propagate changes to listeners via the adapter.

```
var pushedRecord = store.push(model, model_json);
pushedRecord.save();
```

Also if you have multiple records you can call `pushMany` instead of pushing each individually. You still have to save each.

```
store.pushMany(model, jsonArray).forEach function (pushedInstance) {
  pushedInstance.save();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call save(). just adding is enough.