# Bind ArrayController model to Store / synchronize ArrayController with Store

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I'm currently struggling with the Arraycontroller and it's model. It does not change at all, if the data changes in the store. Especially if records are appended to the store, I want the arraycontroller who handles those entries to be updated with the store together. I thought there is some databinding, but it does not seem so at all.

Let's say I have this route: `/#/institute/10/user-administration`

The institute model looks like

```
App.Institute = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('user', {async:true})
});
```

Thats how I set the model of the Arraycontroller:

```
App.UserAdministrationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function() {
    // get users from the current institute
    return this.modelFor('institute').get("users").then(function(users) {
      return users.filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
        // filter anonymous dummy users
        return item.get('name') != "~dummy~";
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And in the UserAdministration-Controller I do

```
App.UserAdministrationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['institute'],
  actions : {
    createNewUser : function() {
      var newUser = this.store.createRecord('User', {
        role : 0
      });
      this.transitionToRoute('user-administration.edit', newUser);
    }
  }
});
```

And in the route `user-administration.edit` I save the user with `this.get('model').save();`

But the ArrayController does not get updated with the just newly created and saved record in the store.
I suppose there is maybe a way if I hook the controller model onto a `filter`, but how would I define a filter for the way I define the ArrayController's model.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it a bit more and taking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639739/update-view-when-pushing-models-to-the-store) in concern, I could figure it out myself. The ArrayController was actually not really bound to the store because I didn't set a store.filter as the model.

To achieve that the Arraycontroller was always synchronized with the data of the store, I had to define a filter as a model. The modeldefiniton in my route now looks like this and works like a charme!

```
App.UserAdministrationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function() {
    var scope = this;
    return this.modelFor('institute').get("users").then(function(){
      return scope.store.filter('user', function(user){
        return user.get('name') != "~dummy~";
      });
    });
  }
});
```

There is a huge difference between filtering and quering for data, I only had to realize that: [SHOULD I USE A QUERY OR A FILTER TO SEARCH RECORDS?](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/)

Comment: Happy to see my answer to another question helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the binding is async, I think you need to explicitly set the association (see https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1532).

```
App.UserAdministrationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['institute'],
  actions : {
    createNewUser : function() {
      var newUser = this.store.createRecord('User', {
        role : 0
      });

      // NEW
      this.get('controllers.institute.model.users').then(function(users) {
        users.addObject(newUser);
      });
      // END NEW

      this.transitionToRoute('user-administration.edit', newUser);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. that makes sense and I should probably do that in anyway, but unfortunately it still does not update the array of users in the content/model of the `UserAdministrationController`. It feels like the model of the ArrayController is not bound to the store at all.